# Buttons click events only works once

Tags: jquery, button, click

I have two buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Save</button>

<button type="button" id="get" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i> Get</button>
```

Each button call a specific javascript function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#save" ).click(function() {
               ...my code...
    });

    $( "#get" ).click(function() {
               ...my code...
   });
});
```

Everything works good except for this example:
If I press my "Get" button I get my result But if after I press "save" button nothing happens.
I need to refresh the page by click again in one button. 
Why can I click multiples times ?

Comment: Why have you added event handler for button `"#save"` 2 times? According to me one has to be `#get` right?

Comment: After changing one of the ids works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/59ugdf23/

Comment: i think you add #save two time. why ????????? can you put all part of code?

Comment: I think the problem is not that he got the #save two times. This is an example and i think he just copy/pasted it and forgot to change. As he said:  "If I press my "Get" button I get my result But if after I press "save" button nothing happens." so that means he got a function for #get button. Can you please share all your code to help? I don't see any issue with this code you shared, except that you forgot to change the second id...

Comment: Guys,

Sorry for my copy past... It's get instead save!

Comment: Then update your code please, if you still need help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 `$( "#save" ).click(function(){})`

make the second one `#get`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#save").click(function () {
        alert('clicked save');
    });

    $("#get").click(function () {
        alert('clicked get');
    });
});
```